# Remove duplicates in MySQL 5.7.12 without using ID

Tags: mysql

I need to append new data (TableB) to old table(TableA). Then remove duplicates. I have tried two version. One work. Another doesnt. The method that is working, requires me to add primary key. Is it possible to skip this?

```
/* Append new data to old table */
insert into TableA select * from TableB;

/* First method does not work */
ALTER IGNORE TABLE TableA ADD UNIQUE (stock, date)

/* Second method work but requires ID. My actual table is very large with millions of rows and hundreds of columns. I will need to create index for fast queries. Hence it is better not to add un-necessary columns */

ALTER TABLE TableA
  ADD ID INT auto_increment primary key;

delete TableA
from TableA
join
( select stock, date, min(id) as theMin,count(*) as theCount 
  from TableA 
  group by stock, date 
  having theCount>1
) xxx 
on TableA.stock = xxx.stock and TableA.date = xxx.date and TableA.id>xxx.theMin
```

Any ideas?

Thanks alot
LL

Comment: you ought to have a PK anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you add a Primary Key (that every self-respecting table should have anyway).

```
create table fish
(   theName varchar(100) not null
);
insert fish(theName) values ('tuna'),('herring');

alter table fish add column `id` int primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

show create table fish;
CREATE TABLE `fish` (
   `theName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

select * from fish;
+---------+----+
| theName | id |
+---------+----+
| tuna    |  1 |
| herring |  2 |
+---------+----+
```

Example 2:

```
create table t8
(   stock varchar(100) not null,
    `date` date not null,
    other int not null
);
insert t8(stock,`date`,other) values ('a','2008-01-01',1),('b','2008-01-01',1);

alter table t8 add primary key (stock,`date`);

show create table t8;
CREATE TABLE `t8` (
   `stock` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `date` date NOT NULL,
   `other` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`stock`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

then pursue an `INSERT IGNORE` strategy for the inserts. See comments below.

Comment: How about if i use the variable names, "stock" and "date" as the primary key and also for index? I dont think the primary key for just numbering is necessary. Also I think my primary key numbering will be very large. Each table has 10 Million rows. I have about 50 such tables to append to one another. After removing duplicates, I dont think the numbering of primary key will reset and auto-increment again.

Comment: If you had a column (or a composite of say 2) that is/are unique, sure.

Comment: See edit. The good thing about that is that you could do an `INSERT IGNORE` into it, and it would ignore dupes, if that is what would have happened. So, it inserts the ones that aren't dupes, and ignores the dupes. `INSERT IGNORE` is just like `insert` except with the word ignore after it.

Comment: I just add "primary keys" to the variables. And use "insert ignore". I got warning messages about duplicates but it turns out well. The most simple way to remove duplicates! Thanks

Comment: yw sir anytime.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

`SELECT hometeam FROM stats GROUP BY hometeam ORDER BY hometeam`

Comment: Other values in the same row will be removed as long they are identified as duplicates. I think i will stick to MySQL language. Thanks

Comment: That is 'mysql language' I am using PHP to issue a mysql query if you want to just enter a mysql statement/query then:-

SELECT hometeam
FROM stats
GROUP BY hometeam
ORDER BY hometeam

Comment: I am totally baffled - I answered question, gave example and get voted down ?????

Comment: the OP asked for pure mySQL, not for mySQL within a PHP context. Consider re-writing it without the PHP and you might succeed more.

Comment: My bad - amended question without php by the way Drew the question was how to do it without a unique id - not how to create a unique id.  At least you didn't get voted down. :-)

Comment: *The method that is working, requires me to add primary key. Is it possible to skip this?* Why should he skip it? Why would having a PK (which it should have) be damaging? Especially when you want to isolate a row to delete (that is what a PK is for, isolating a row)

Comment: Look at your Version 1 of your answer. And I didn't downvote you. I don't DV fellow answer people unless it is like absurd, like 1 out of 500 times

Comment: The OP had a routine that worked fine so he said if he had a PK. Bingo I gave him one. Also learn how to use this site. I don't get pings in my inbox just because you say btw Drew or @Drew under *your* Answer. Further, get 50 points so you can comment anywhere. We look forward to you contributing now and then. Just do it the right way, not like your Version 1

Comment: OK calm down just pointing out question title was 'Remove duplicates in MySQL 5.7.12 without using ID'

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.